# How do i convert this logic to pinescript v5?

Tags: logic, pine-script

I would please like some help to translate this logic to pinescript v4 or v5 as i keep on getting the following errors on line 05 - 07 with the logic saying undeclared identifiers `TrendUp`, `TrendDown` and `TrendDef`

```
01 Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 000,)

02 Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)

03 Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))

04 Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))

05 TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up

06 TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

07 Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)

08 plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Arrow", colorup=color.new(color.lime, 85), maxheight=200, minheight=50)

09 plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Arrow", colordown=color.new(color.red, 85), maxheight=200, minheight=50)
```

Much Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this modified code...

```
//@version = 4
study("TREND")
Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 000)

Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)

Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))

Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))


float TrendUp = 0.0, float TrendDown = 0.0, float Trend = 0.0

TrendUp :=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up

TrendDown :=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],0)

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Arrow", colorup=color.new(color.lime, 85), maxheight=200, minheight=50)

plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Arrow", colordown=color.new(color.red, 85), maxheight=200, minheight=50)
```

Comment: I was struggling to define TrendUp as TrendUp = close or TrendUp = close[0] and it was not giving me the correct logic results. I guess what it was looking for was a int/float container assigned to the variable as opposed to the price value i was trying to assign to the variables. Lesson learnt. You're solution helped fix it. Thank you very much for your spontaneous response :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an [Assignment Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#reassignement-operator)